# Como implementar em DDD uma camada de exportação/importação de arquivos de texto e como ela se relacionará com as demais camadas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, ddd

Estou me baseando em um projeto do Eduardo Pires [Aqui](https://github.com/EduardoPires/EquinoxProject) e estou com algumas dúvidas sobre implementação de uma camada exclusiva para a importação e exportação de informações do banco em formato csv, txt, xls, dentre outros. Para isso, eu criei como parte da Infraestrutura, uma camada InputOutput onde criarei métodos de importação e exportação para cada classe.

Dúvida 1: Para criar tais métodos eu preciso fazer um repositório genérico parecido com aquele que usamos na camada Data para fazer o CRUD no Banco de dados com o EF, por exemplo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dúvida 2 - Sobre os Serviços e Domínio: Na minha camada Application eu já tenho os serviços para fazer o CRUD que Mapeiam e direcionam para classes Command da camada de Domínio para fazer validações e gravar/consultar as informações do banco. 
Por se tratar de Exportações, eu preciso construir classes command em meu domínio e do domínio direcionar o fluxo para a camada InputOutput ou simplesmente, da classe de serviço eu direciono o fluxo diretamente para a camada InputOutput sem passar pelo Domínio e não validar nada? 
Tenho dúvidas se precisaria validar, pois já que os dados estão tratados no banco, seria só gravá-los em um arquivo de texto.

Muito grato a todos que puderem me ajudar!!!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

**Dúvida 1:** Faz mais sentido você referenciar o projeto Data no seu projeto Exportações já que você precisará acessar o banco de dados de qualquer jeito e precisará de todas as estruturas de dados que já estão definidas no projeto Data.

**Dúvida 2:** No geral todas as funcionalidades passam pelo Domain, principalmente projetos que usam CQRS para desacoplar a leitura da escrita. Sua funcionalidade pode ser apenas retornar um arquivo agora, mas futuramente ela evoluir e registrar um log das chamadas de exportação, por exemplo. Desenvolver essa nova funcionalidade será bem menos custoso se já existir uma representação dela na camada de domínio, ainda que seja para uma funcionalidade bem simples.

Da próxima vez, por gentileza, faça uma pergunta para cada dúvida, ainda que sejam relacionadas.